# Authenticating a user from a view model?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've setup a simple ASP MVC project with custom forms authentication. I am also using Entity Framework so I currently have a domain model from EF called Account and a view model called AccountViewModel. When it comes to authenticating a user I was previously doing this in my Account/Auth action which would be posted to from Account/Login where the login form is.

However, I know it's not a great idea to have business logic within controllers so I felt like I should move it into a model. Is it ok to move this kind of logic into my view model? Below is my view model:

```
Public Class AccountViewModel

    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Password As String

    Public Function Authenticate() As Boolean
        Using context As New DbContext
            Dim emailMatch = (From acc In context.Accounts
                              Where acc.Email = Me.Email).FirstOrDefault
            If Not emailMatch Is Nothing Then
                If emailMatch.FailedLogins < 5 Then
                    If Me.Password = emailMatch.Password Then
                        emailMatch.FailedLogins = 0
                        context.SaveChanges()
                        Return True
                    Else
                        emailMatch.FailedLogins += 1
                        context.SaveChanges()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End Using
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

I then handle setting the authentication cookie in my controller, in response to the return from this function.

```
'POST: /Account/Auth
Function Auth(account As AccountViewModel) As ActionResult
    If account.Authenticate Then FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(account.Email, False)
    Return RedirectToAction("Index")
End Function
```

Comment: No. A view model should generally contain only properties and not methods, especially ones that access the database (you have made it impossible to unit test your code). That code belongs in your controller, or in a separate service called by the controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke What kind of separate service?

Comment: For example a `class AcountService` with a method `public bool Authenticate(string Email, string Password)` (c# code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Out of curiosity, where would I place that? App_Code?

Comment: Anywhere you want. In the controller method. In the controller as a private method. In a separate assembly (I use a folder named 'Data', but 'Repository' is another common name)